# React componet should be written as a pure function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my ReactJs component code:

```
import React from 'react';

     class App extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
                </div>
                );
        }
     }

    export default App;
```

Linting is showing me the following error:

```
 error  Component should be written as a pure function  react/prefer-stateless-function
```

How to write that as a pure function to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
   return (
     <div className="wrapper">
          <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Components that do not need to keep state are called "stateless", and are usually considered best practice to use unless you need to keep state.

Comment: This leaded to another error: `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body  arrow-body-style`.

Comment: You should use this syntax:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e812549e391f9f2bec85f678e397567

Answer (score 3):

A simple function will suffice, you don't need an entire class (that should be only used for stateful components). You can reduce the code to

```
import React from 'react';

export default const App = () => (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
  </div>
);
```

or

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this:

```
import React from 'react';

var App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Reason** is: You are not using an state or any lifecycle method in this, so you can make it as Pure Function. It is basically know as `Stateless Functional Component`.

Check the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

 const App = (props) => (
   <div className="wrapper">
     <h1>Welcome to App!!!!</h1>
   </div>
 );

export default App;
```